# Swift/Xcode6 AVAudioPlayer crashes when I call ".stop()" method

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, avaudioplayer

in my class "AudioHub" i have this code

```
 var myAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
func audioPlayer(audioName: String ) {
    println("hey")
    var error:NSError?
    if let audioURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(audioName, withExtension: "mp3") {
        myAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioURL, error: &error)
        myAudioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        myAudioPlayer.play()
    } else if let error = error {
        println(error.description)
    }
}
```

in my ViewController class i initialize my AudioHub class with

```
var bridge = AudioHub()
```

in my ViewControllers viewDidLoad method i call

```
bridge.playAudio("testSound")
```

it starts playing the sound fine... however, i have another method imbedded inside a button in my ViewController class that is supposed to stop the audio from playing with this code:

```
bridge.stop()
```

whenever i click on the button the program crashes with the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error... i think the issue has something to do with calling the method from a different class, because when i keep everything inside of one class nothing goes wrong. however i need an inter-class solution.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here with .stop() on AVMIDIPlayer.
Super simple method:

```
func stopMIDIPLayer() {
    if let mp = self.mp {
        if mp.playing {
            mp.stop()
        }
    }
}
```

My player is a singleton and I'm also calling the stopMIDIPlayer() method from my viewController.

Comment: Is this the solution?